# SQL: I would like to replace a building number with its proper name

Tags: javascript, sql, asp.net, stored-procedures

I have a veterinarian SQL server, and I am building a stored procedure using SSMS in ASP.NET. I have a working SQL query that fetches all clinical cases between two dates:

```
USE [vetDatabase_Wizard]
GO
ALTER PROCEDURE sp_GetNewCases (@startDate datetime, @endDate datetime)
AS
BEGIN 
    SELECT caseID,building FROM tblCases
    WHERE dateOpened BETWEEN @startDate and @endDate
END
GO
EXEC sp_GetNewCases '2015-01-01', '2015-08-30'
```

Thanks to the online community, it is working! :)

Here is the output:

```
caseID   building
1        3
2        3
3        2
...
```

When I started learning how to make SQL databases, I was told that it is good practice to store the building name with a respective number to save storage space. For example, tblBuildings:

```
buildingID     name
1              GSC
2              RVH
3              MMD
...
```

I have 7 building names. I would like to modify my stored procedure above, so that I can use the output (in JSON format) with some javascript data visualization libraries:

```
caseID         name
1              MMD
2              MMD
3              RVH
...
```

Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: You mix several question at the same time. Are you asking about the db design, store procedure, json or asp? Try to be specific, otherwise is too broad to answer. Please read [**How-to-Ask**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
 
 And here is a great place to [**START**](http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) to learn how improve your question quality and get better answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First you should change the tblCases field name `building` to `building_id` so will be consistent with your other table.

Then join both table together so you can return `building_name`, you may remove `building_id` from result if you dont need it.

```
BEGIN 
    SELECT C.caseID, B.building_id, B.Name 
    FROM tblCases C
    JOIN tblBuilding B
      ON C.building_id = B.building_id
    WHERE dateOpened BETWEEN @startDate and @endDate
END
```

Comment: Hi! Thank you very much for your help! I learned something new! :D Moreover, I will be careful in making better questions. I didn't know that we could use letters (i.e. B,C) to identify fields in such a flexible way. I wanted to ask you also: I don't need to write C.dateOpened because we mention "FROM tblCases", right?

Comment: You should write `C.dateOpened` to make your code more readable for next guy. But you dont have to. In the case of `building_id` you **have to** because db wouldnt know which of those two are you refering to and would  be ambiguous. That is called `Alias` and you can do it for tables or fieldnames too.